# Add own sensor to lm_sensors?

Tags: linux, i2c, atmega, smbus

I have a PCIe connected to my linux server and want to use SMBus pins to communicate via I2C to a slave uC (atmega128). This slave will, similarly, read some temperature also via I2C (the wires are multiplexed by a signal controlled by the uC, so it can be slave/master depending on the state of this signal). In master mode, the uC can get all the information from the sensors attached to it. In slave mode, the linux server will be seeing this device and will be able to ask for the information. Now, my question is:

How can I get my device to appear in the list shown when we write "sensor" in the console with the library lm_sensors installed? I have no idea what is the format in which the data is sent to this library, or whatever I would need to do. Would really appreciate some help!

Thanks!